# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `date` is marked as required in `CalendarProvider`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im new on react-native app and im trying to get agenda selected day data but i cant take it and when i debug it is writing the prop date is marked but its undefined. And i cant take selected date data. Here is my Agenda screen code:

```
export default class AgendaScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      markedDates: this.getMarkedDates(),
      isVisibleItems: false,
      onDayPress: { dateString: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD") }
    };
  }
  buttonPressed() {
    Alert.alert("show more");
  }

  getMarkedDates = () => {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const marked = {};
    items.calendar
      ? items.calendar.forEach(item => {
        // only mark dates with data
        if (
          item.data &&
          item.data[1].limit == 0 &&
          item.data[0].limit == 0 &&
          !_.isEmpty(item.data[0])
        ) {
          marked[item.title] = { marked: true };
        }
      })
      : null;
    return marked;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isVisibleItems: true });
  }
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { isVisibleItems, onDayPress } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 15, zIndex: 0 }}>
        <CalendarProvider >
          <ExpandableCalendar
            firstDay={1}
            markedDates={this.getMarkedDates()}
            theme={this.getTheme()}
            minDate={new Date()}
            onDayPress={day => {
              this.setState({ isVisibleItems: true, onDayPress: day });
            }}
          />
        </CalendarProvider>
        {isVisibleItems ? this.renderItem(onDayPress) : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

lookslike my getMarkedDates function is not working
 idk why

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your CalendarProvider component you have set date as required and now you should provide it like `<CalendarProvider date = {date} >`, also try to call getMarkedDates function in componentDidMount instead of the constructor.